# I need to delete an MKLINK /J in Windows 10 18242.1000.180914-1435.RS_PRERELEASE_CLIENTPRO_OEMRET_x64FRE_ES-ES

Tags: windows, command-line, microsoft-office, symbolic-link

yesterday (Madrid`s time) I've created, using Admin elevated Command Prompt the following two junctions (they´re of course in castilian), in order to try to install the new Office 2019 C2R on P: instead than to C:.
It failed: Office does fails at installing uncompleting install.

Commands used:

```
MKLINK /J "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15" "P:\Archivos de programa\Ofimática\MS Oficina 2019"

MKLINK /J "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office" "P:\Archivos de programa\Ofimática\MS Oficina 2019"
```

Now I'm trying all the way to remove the junction; I also entered, from the Admin elevated Command Prompt the `P:\Archivos de programa\Ofimática` directory, but both RD and rmdir return me a reply that ¨The system cant find the speficied file¨ when its still visible in Windows Explorer (refreshed with F5).

Whats is supposed have I to do to eliminate that MKLINK /J command I gave?
Any real working trick is welcome.

Comment: Go to C:\Program Files in a command prompt as administrator, type `rd Mic` and press tab to autocomplete to the right path and press enter. That should remove it.

Comment: Confirm with dir. If it doesn't say junction, then the installer already removed the junction and its an actual folder.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the main issue here lies in the wording

> "in order to try to install the new Office 2019 C2R on P: instead than
>   to C:"

As LPChip correctly points out (implicitly, I'm afraid) you have created the link on C: not on P: as you desired. The mklink command on windows behaves rather 'backwards' compared to the instinctive notion of "source" "destination" one is used to. (And in Linux' ln command.)

- On windows it's mklink /J linkto linksource
- On Linux (*ux?) it's ln -s linksource linkto
  Which is the intuitive one (opinion?). I here treat JUNCTION like symbolic links, which should be good enough in this setting.

My guess to what happened here is that you created an invalid (pointer created but nothing to resolv to) JUNCTION (or symlink if you want to call it that) that later got populated on Office Install so that it got resolvable (populated).
With this in mind you may even want to try reinstalling Office this way, although it may be safer to use the Registry modification of the ProgramFilesDir entries. I HATE it when apps don't give the option of choosing the install location. "Let's fill up your SSD" kind of (lack of) thinking. (Rantmode off.)